# Special verbs for animals giving birth

Tags: дієслова

Say, mother pig gives birth to a baby pig. Is there a special verb for that in Ukrainian?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, such verb exists in Ukrainian language:

[ОПОРОСИ́ТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/oporosytysja)

> ОПОРОСИ́ТИСЯ, роситься, док. **Народити, привести поросят (про
>   свиню).** *Свинарка Катя прибігла до правління колгоспу з радісним
>   криком: — Волга опоросилась! Аж сімнадцятеро!* (Остап Вишня, II, 1956,
>   96).

---

**Update (thanks to [Oksana Gubrenko](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/435/oksana-gubrenko)).**

For cow you can use:

[ОТЕЛЮВАТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/OTELJuVATYSJa)

> ОТЕЛЮВАТИСЯ, юється, недок., ОТЕЛИТИСЯ, елиться, док. **Народжувати теля
>   (про корів та інших великих жуйних тварин).** *[Никодим:] Там отелилася
>   корова, ти б пішла подивилася — нехай при тобі видоять її, телятко
>   погодують* (Карпенко-Карий, I, 1960, 441); *— І шкода, Романе, тебе на
>   пісному тримати. Хоч би корова швидше отелилася* (Михайло Стельмах, I,
>   1962, 306).

For sheep, goats, cat and some other mammals:

[ОКОЧУВАТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/OKOChUVATYSJa)

> ОКОЧУВАТИСЯ, ується, недок., рідко, ОКОТИТИСЯ, окотиться, док.
>   **Народжувати малят (про овець, кіз, котячих та деяких інших ссавців)** —
>   *Корова, сама знаєш, щороку приводить теля, конячка — дає лоша, вівця —
>   окочується ягнятком.* (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 311).

Also you can find this verb in popular Ukrainian national song "Щедрик, щедрик, щедрівочка":

> – Вийди, вийди, господарю,
>   Подивися на кошару,
>   Там **овечки покотились**,
>   А **ягнички народились**.

Verb *окочуватись* in case of lambs has a synonym:

> [ЯГНИ́ТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/jaghnytysja), ягниться, недок. Народжувати ягнят; окочуватися.

---

**Update 2 (thanks to [Nash Bridges](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/36/nash-bridges))**

For dogs, wolves and foxes:

> [ОЩЕНИ́ТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/oshhenytysja), ощениться, док., ЩЕНИТИСЯ, щениться, недок. Народжувати щеня.

For horces:

> [ЖЕРЕБИТИСЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zherebytysja), ребиться, недок. Народжувати лоша. Коні весело іржуть,
>   кобили жеребляться (Остап Вишня, I, 1956, 410).